# Am not able to install capybara-webkit in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, ubuntu-14.04, capybara-webkit

how can i install capybara-webkit 
here am using rails/ruby versios are 3.2.12/1.9.3

```
 Installing capybara-webkit 0.13.0 with native extensions

 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/rguda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392-railsexpress/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151124-3867-3fgy4k.rb extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec linux-g++' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rguda/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392-railsexpress@rails3.2.12/gems/capybara-webkit-0.13.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rguda/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392-railsexpress@rails3.2.12/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/capybara-webkit-0.13.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (0.13.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.13.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: have you downloaded and installed `qt` ? https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Comment: still am facing same issue

Comment: you did `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev` right?

Comment: yes.
$qmake -v

#QMake version 2.01a

#Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
------------------------
$which qmake

# /usr/local/bin/qmake

Comment: ok, so did you retry to `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.13.0'`?

Comment: This error came
--------------------
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
 mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

Comment: you should upgrade your ruby version to 2.0 or greater

Comment: but its already developed project which has ruby version 1.9.3 only. Recently i joined, and am facing this issue whenever i did "bundle install"

Comment: you can try with `gem install mime-types -v 2.6.2'`

Comment: thanks a lot  fabersky.. Its working fine for me :)

Comment: great! I added it as an answer as it worked for you

Comment: can you please accept the answer @user748447 ?

Answer (score 1):

Install `qt`, the run `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`and `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.13.0'`.
As you have the error `Error installing capybara-webkit: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0`, it means you have to install a previous version of the gem, so run `gem install mime-types -v 2.6.2'`